# Declare and set a variable with more than one possible value

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, variables, declare, table-variable

Is it possible to set a variable to have more than one value?

In the example below, I would like to set the `@variable` and use store numbers 1,4,7 and 12

And then use the variable in the `WHERE` statment.

The below is purely an example to see if this is possible or not

```
Declare @Variable INT;

Set @Variable = IN(1,4,7,12)

Select *
From dbo.EUactivestores eu
Where eu.[Store No] = @Variable
```

Any advice on if this is possible, or something similar would be great.

I believe it could help with making a more dynamic query

Comment: You can use a table variable.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use a table variable like here

```
DECLARE @tbl TABLE(v INT);
INSERT INTO @tbl VALUES(1),(4),(7),(12);
```

You can use this in `WHERE` clause like here:

```
WHERE eu.[Store No] IN(SELECT v FROM @tbl);
```

### Fully working example:

```
DECLARE @tbl TABLE(v INT);
INSERT INTO @tbl VALUES(1),(4),(7),(12);

DECLARE @mockup TABLE(ID INT IDENTITY,SomeValue VARCHAR(100));
INSERT INTO @mockup VALUES('val 1'),('val 2'),('val 3'),('val 4'),('val 5')
                         ,('val 6'),('val 7'),('val 8'),('val 9'),('val 10')
                         ,('val 11'),('val 12'),('val 13'),('val 14'),('val 15');
```

--only values from your table

```
SELECT * FROM @mockup AS m
WHERE m.ID IN(SELECT v FROM @tbl);
```

--or the negation of the above

```
SELECT * FROM @mockup AS m
WHERE m.ID NOT IN(SELECT v FROM @tbl);
```

Comment: This is exactly what i needed !#